# How do I generate options based on Ajax callback

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

In Drupal 8, I want to generate options of second select-box based on Ajax call of first select-box. The result generate a third new select box but I don't need to generate a new one. I want to replace the options of the second select-box. Please see my codes below:

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$form['example_select'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
  'wrapper' => 'first',
  '#options' => [
    '1' => $this->t('One'),
    '2' => $this->t('Two'),
    '3' => $this->t('Three'),
    '4' => $this->t('From New York to Ger-ma-ny!'),
  ],
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback', 
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE, 
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-output', 
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ]
];


$form['example_select2'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="first">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#options' => [
  ],
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback2', 
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-output', 
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ]
];
return $form;
}

public function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($selectedValue = $form_state->getValue('example_select')) {
    $arr = array('1' => 'Nice way', '2' => 'Good way');
    $form['example_select2']['#options'] = $arr;
  }
  return $form['example_select2'];
}
```

Comment: you probably want to use == instead of = in if ($selectedValue == $form_state->getValue('example_select'))

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `'wrapper' => 'first'` that exist in the `example_select`.
2. Set `'#ajax'=> 'wrapper'` elements to  `'first'`, actually this is the id of element that will be updated, in your case `<div id="first">` that you create using the `prefix` and `suffix` in `$form['example_select2']`
3. This is an extra step, for some reason it will work but you'll get an error if you don't add `'#validated' => 'true'`, to `$form['example_select2']`
4. in the ajax callback function `myAjaxCallback` you need to apply some logic that enables you to create form select options dynamically based on the choice you made in the first slect box (see the code bellow )

full code that has been tested in my machine and it works 100% :

[image]

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['example_select'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
      '#options' => [
        '1' => $this->t('One'),
        '2' => $this->t('Two'),
        '3' => $this->t('Three'),
        '4' => $this->t('From New York to Ger-ma-ny!'),
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback',
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
        'event' => 'change',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        ],
        // The wrapper actually is the id of the element that
        // the ajax response will be injected into
        // it must be isndie the '#ajax" element.
        'wrapper' => 'first',
      ],
    ];

    $form['example_select2'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
      // The "wrapper" id that the ajax response will be injected into
      // must have an id ="wrapper set on select 1 form'.
      '#prefix' => '<div id="first">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      // for some reason you  need to set '#validated' => 'true' other wise tou get :
      // An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
      '#validated' => 'true',
      '#options' => [],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback2',
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        ],
      ],
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  public function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // 1.construct an array of choices
    // make the key = your select '#options' key
    // and value = options values that you want to use in example_select2.
    $arr = [
      '1' => ['first','uno','first one','Best'],
      '2' => ['Second','2nd place','not first'],
      '3' => ['Third','Three',''],
      '4' => ['Fourth','four','las one'],
    ];

    // 2.Get the selected option value
    // ex : 3
    $selctedOption = $form_state->getValue("example_select");

    // 3.Choose an array based on the selected option value.
    // ex : $arr['3']
    $form['example_select2']['#options'] = $arr[$selctedOption];

    return $form['example_select2'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working well forme.

```
public function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($selectedValue = $form_state->getValue('example_select')) {
    $arr = array('1' => 'Nice way', '2' => 'Good way');
    $form['example_select2']['#options'] = $arr;
  }
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#first", ($form['example_select2'])));
  return $response;
}
```